# Let $X$ be partially ordered set. We say that $U$ is open if $(x \in U \land x\le y) \Rightarrow y\in U$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\le)$ be a poset. We define open set $U$ when the following condition is satisfied
$(x \in U \land x\le y) \Rightarrow y\in U$.

I have to show that, the family of open sets defined aboved is a topology on $X$.

I've read the article about Alexandrov topology, but still I don't know how to show, that it is topology.

Comment: Which conditions does the family have to fulfil to be a topology?

Comment: i) The whole space (it is trivial), the nullset (it has no elements at all so the condition is satisfied)
ii) Intersection of each two open sets should be also open (don't know how to write that down correct).
I mean, I don't know how to check whether that conition is fulfiled. How do we operate on this $\le$ order?

Comment: That should be "union", not "sum" in iii). Okay, so let's look at ii). Say $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open. Let $U = U_1 \cap U_2$. Suppose $x \in U$. Let $x \leq y$ …

Comment: So from the conditions $U_{1}, U_{2}$ we get, that $y \in U$? And that's it?

Comment: There is a step, or two, depends on how you count, in between. But basically, that's it. For the union, the argument is similar.

Comment: @DanielFischer could you please describe it formally? I mean, these steps? It would good for me to remember how to write it down properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46937/discussion-between-janusz-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the family of thus defined "open" sets is a topology, we need to verify the condition

$$(x \in U \land x \leq y) \implies y \in U\tag{1}$$

for some sets.

It is clear that $(1)$ holds for $U = X$, since then the conclusion $y\in U$ always holds. And $(1)$ holds (vacuously) for $U = \varnothing$, since the antecedent is always false.

Next we verify that the intersection of two "open" sets is an open set. So let $U_1,U_2$ be open, and set $U = U_1 \cap U_2$. We must verify that

$$x \leq y \implies y \in U$$

holds for every $x \in U$. Hence let $x \in U$ and $x \leq y$. Since $U = U_1 \cap U_2$, we have $x \in U_k$ for $k \in \{1,2\}$. Since $U_k$ is open, and $x \leq y$, it follows that $y \in U_k,\, k \in \{1,2\}$. But that is just $y \in U_1 \cap U_2$, or equivalently $y\in U$. Thus $(1)$ is verified for $U = U_1 \cap U_2$. In other words, the intersection of two open sets is open.

Finally, we need to show that an arbitrary union of open sets is open. So let $I$ be an arbitrary index set, and for every $i \in I$ let $U_i$ be an open set. Let

$$U = \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i.$$

Suppose $x \in U$, and $x \leq y$. By definition, $x\in U \iff (\exists i \in I)(x \in U_i)$. Choose such an index $i_0$. Since $U_{i_0}$ is open, we have

$$(x \in U_{i_0} \land x \leq y) \implies y \in U_{i_0}.$$

The antecedent of that is true by assumption, and hence we conclude $y\in U_{i_0}$. But $U_{i_0} \subset U$, and thus $y \in U$, showing that $U$ is open.

Comment: Thank you very much @Daniel for making me wiser!